# On Centos7 firewalld overwrite iptables modules

Tags: iptables, firewalld

Simple question: i want to load two modules

```
/usr/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp 
/usr/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

I can put those lines in rc.local or use /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
But at reboot firewalld overwrite my choices and doesn't load modules
Question : how to instructe firewalld to load those two modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Centos 7 uses `systemd`, so files named `*.conf` in `/etc/modules-load.d/` can be used to configure which kernel modules are loaded at boot.

e.g.

```
echo ip_nat_ftp > /etc/modules-load.d/iptables.conf
echo ip_conntrack_ftp >> /etc/modules-load.d/iptables.conf
```

You can specify any options for those modules or blacklist unwanted modules using the usual `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` method.

See `man 5 modules-load.d`, `man 5 modprobe.d` and `man 8 systemd-modules-load.service` for more details.

---

PS: in debian and derivatives, you can just list them one-per-line in `/etc/modules`.  `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` is also used to specify module options and blacklisting.

Comment: I like this solution,i try after a reload of firewall zone